# How can I run 'android update project' from within Eclipse using ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, adt

I'm migrating an Android build system from ADT to mostly-out-of-the-box Ant and would like to make it as painless as possible for devs. A fresh checkout doesn't contain local.properties (as advised, and which makes perfect sense), and the build yells at you:

```
sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 
'android update project' or to inject it through the ANDROID_HOME 
environment variable.
```

Either of these steps is tedious enough that doing it after every fresh checkout is unsavory under Windows. Given that the ADT knows the SDK location (and that's all we really need), is there any way to spit the file out without having to drop into `cmd` drill into Windows env vars?

I tried Project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties, but that doesn't seem to take care of local.properties.

Comment: You definitely need to run `android update project`. Whether there is way of doing that from inside Eclipse, I can't say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do it. Eclipse with ADT uses a different mechanisms for some parts of the build project. 
I'm not sure why setting ANDROID_HOME is tedious to do after every checkout. You only need to set it once.

Comment: `Start > Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > New > Type key+value by hand`. 

Compare to `Right Click > Android > Make me a local.properties`. 

That's why I say tedious. Not the end of the world, but I know people will complain.